# iPhone only showing purchased music

Tags: iphone, itunes, music

Today I was editing my music library, deleting old songs and such, and then of course, synced my iTunes to my iPhone. Everything synced fine until I realized my iPhone was only showing music purchased from iTunes. Nothing I downloaded nor my CD's were showing up. My playlists were all gone as well. I have tried to sync multiple times today and nothing has worked. I am NOT on iTunes Match.